# Is WebStorm console different to native OS X console?

Tags: macos, terminal, protractor, webstorm

When I am running my e2e tests in WebStorm console its all fine, no fails etc. but when I try to run them in mac Terminal its failing.

Currently I am using framework based on Protractor. When tests are running on system console all animations are like `z-index` is like 100 and rest of elements are under it, so WebDriver Protractor is unable to click them.

Any clues?

I checked `printenv` but it seems to be the same.

Comment: What WebStorm console are you talking about - its built-in terminal, or console that opens when you run Protractor run configuration, or? Do you use the same web server for running protractor tests from webStorm and from system terminal?

Comment: @lena I'm talking about buillt-in terminal. All the same

Comment: there should be no difference then. the only (possible) difference is the environment variables in native and built-in console